# Почему при создании комментария создается его дубликат?

Tags: python, django

Добавляю комментарий и создается его дубликат в виде ответа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**views.py**

```
class MoreDetailsQuestion(SuccessMessageMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
model = Questions
template_name = 'blog/more_q.html'
pk_url_kwarg = 'q_pk'
context_object_name = 'more_q'
form_class = AnswerForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('question')
success_msg = 'Запись успешно обновлена'


def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('question', kwargs={'q_pk':self.get_object().id})

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = context['more_q']
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.POST.get("parent", None):
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent"))
            if parent_id:
                parent_obj = Answer.objects.get(id=parent_id)
                if parent_obj:
                    replay_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                    replay_comment.parent = parent_obj
        return self.form_valid(form)

    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.post = self.get_object()
    self.object.author = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**шаблон**

```
    <form action="." method="post" id="formReview">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="parent" id="contactparent" value="">
        <p><textarea id='contactcomment' rows="5" cols="45" name="text"></textarea></p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Добавить ответ"></p>
    </form>

{% for i in more_q.get_answer %}

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="media g-mb-30 media-comment">
            {% if user.photo %}
            <img class="d-flex g-width-50 g-height-50 rounded-circle g-mt-3 g-mr-15" src="{{i.author.photo.url}}" alt="Image Description">
            {%else%}
            <img class="d-flex g-width-50 g-height-50 rounded-circle g-mt-3 g-mr-15" src="{% static 'blog/img/regular_user.jpg'%}" alt="Image Description">
            {%endif%}
            <div class="media-body u-shadow-v18 g-bg-secondary g-pa-30">
              <div class="g-mb-15">
                  <h5 class="">просто ответ</h5>
                <h5 class="h5 g-color-gray-dark-v1 mb-0"><a href="{% url 'show_other_profiles' i.author.id  %}">{{i.author}}</a></h5>
                <span class="g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-font-size-12">{{ i.created|date:"d.m.Y" }}</span>
              </div>


              <p>{{ i.text }}</p>

                <li class="list-inline-item ml-auto">
                  <a class="u-link-v5 g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-color-primary--hover" href="#formReview"   onclick="addReview('{{i.author}}', '{{i.id}}')">
                    <i class='fa fa-reply g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-3'></i>
                    Reply
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

      {% for x in more_q.answer_set.all %}

                            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id='text_answer_answer' class="col-md-7">

        <div class="media g-mb-30 media-comment">

            {% if user.photo %}
            <img class="d-flex g-width-50 g-height-50 rounded-circle g-mt-3 g-mr-15" src="{{x.author.photo.url}}" alt="Image Description">
            {%else%}
            <img class="d-flex g-width-50 g-height-50 rounded-circle g-mt-3 g-mr-15" src="{% static 'blog/img/regular_user.jpg'%}" alt="Image Description">
            {%endif%}
            <div class="media-body u-shadow-v18 g-bg-secondary g-pa-30">
              <div class="g-mb-15">
                  <h5>ответ на ответ</h5>
                <h5 class="h5 g-color-gray-dark-v1 mb-0"><a href="{% url 'show_other_profiles' x.author.id  %}">{{x.author}}</a></h5>
                <span class="g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-font-size-12">{{ x.created|date:"d.m.Y" }}</span>
              </div>
              <p>{{ x.text }}</p>

                <li class="list-inline-item ml-auto">
                  <a class="u-link-v5 g-color-gray-dark-v4 g-color-primary--hover" href="#formReview"   onclick="addReview('{{x.author}}', '{{x.id}}')">
                    <i class='fa fa-reply g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-3'></i>
                    Reply
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(modesl.Model):
          ...
          ...
    def get_answer(self):
        return self.answer_set.filter(parent__isnull=True)


class Answer(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Questions,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
  ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', verbose_name="Родитель", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Автор комментария',default='')
```

{% for x in more_q.answer_set.all %} - извлекает весь QuerySets из модели answer, поэтому есть предположение что виновник именно он

Comment: Вы создаёте комментарий внутри метода post и затем опять создаёте комментарий внутри метода form_valid - ну вроде бы всё логично

Comment: @andreymal, уже час сижу и не могу понять, что именно надо исправить! Помогите пожалуйста!